# Regular expressions optional items

Tags: java, html, regex

If I have this regular expression

```
print_first = print_first.replace(/ T(op Choice)?/gi, "<span class='top_choice'>&nbsp;Top Choice</span>");
```

Shouldn't this match these strings: T, To, Top, Top C, Top Ch, Top Cho, Top Choi, Top Choic, Top Choice?

What would be a better way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire group is made optional, but it is all or nothing not character by character.  So your regex would match the strings `' T'` or `' Top Choice'`.

Unfortunately the regex to get that sort of character by character behavior is pretty ugly.  You need would need a bunch of nested optional groups, something like the following:

```
/ T(o(p( (C(h(o(i(ce?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?/gi
```

Or alternatively, you could use alternation with the `|` character.  The naive approach would be pretty long because you would need to list all of the options, here is an approach that tries to be a little bit clever but is still probably more readable than all of those nested groups:

```
/ Top Choice?| Top Choi?| Top Ch?| Top ?| To?/gi
```

So the first section there would match `' Top Choice'` or `' Top Choic'`, the second section would match `' Top Choi'` or `' Top Cho'`, and so on.  Note that it is very important that the longer sections come first in the regex.

Comment: this also matches `top_choice`, it won't if you remove the `/i`

Comment: This doesn't seem to replace the string with the <span>.

Comment: You should be able to plug this regex into your current code and have it work as expected, could you edit your question to include the string you are working with an the expected result?  In my tests this regex will match the strings you are looking for.

Comment: Although even longer, the regex `T(?:o(?:p(?: (?:C(?:h(?:o(?:i(?:ce?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?` would probably be better as it uses non-capture groups rather then 8 nested capture groups

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to use a non-ugly Regex.  The neatest approach, with respect to coding, is to iterate through the letters and trim off the last one.

```
String r = "TopChoice";
while (r.length() > 0) {
    //Check for match to String r
    r = r.substring(0, r.length() - 1).trim();
}
```